# How do I make a word possessive when there are words after it before the object?

Tags: grammar, possessives

Would I say: "It was the boy's beside her balloon."

Or

"It was the boy beside her's balloon."

I feel like it's the first one, but it sounds weird when I say it out loud.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that the balloon belongs to the boy beside her? If so, then we have a couple of questions already.

Comment: “It was the *boy's ballon* beside her.” (The balloon is beside the girl) “The balloon *belongs to the boy* beside her” (The boy sitting beside the girl is the owner of the balloon) Are you sure you want the word *balloon*, and not "ball"? Not that it makes that much difference.